System Image for emulators: difference between VanillaIceCream and API 35?
I created different emulators to test the app on Android 15. I wasn't sure about these two system images, so I created for both an emulator. And the app behaves differently on the same device type.
So, what is the difference between VanillaIceCream and API 35?

Android 15 has been named as Vanilla Ice cream as google follows a trend to name Android versions on sweets. Vanilla Ice cream Api level is also 35. But there are 2 system images on Android Studio, and the key difference is that Api 35 is the stable release of Android 15. Whereas Vanilla Ice cream has additional experimental features that are still being tested or refined. System image vanilla ice cream is used for testing purposes.

Thank you, now I get it! I was confused because I assumed there is no stable release as it's still in Beta. But know I saw that Beta 3 is stable. https://developer.android.com/about/versions/15/overview

Build number of VanillaIceCream: API31.240426.022.B1
API 35: AE3A.240806.005
I guess it means VanillaIceCream was built at 26 April. And API 35 was built at 6 August.
Use API 35 and it is newer.
